# Why i cannot show my byte[] image after converting it from bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, arrays, scale

I'm trying to write a method that accepts an image(`Bitmap`) and returns a `byte[] array`. finally, I try to write this `byte[] array` to a folder so I can see the difference, but my `byte[] array`can not displayed, and in addition, it is not scaled down! This is my method:

```
private byte[] changeSize(Bitmap image) {
        byte[] picture;
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int newHeight = 0, newWidth = 0;
            if (width > 250 || height > 250) {
                    if (width > height) { //landscape-mode
                        newHeight = 200;
                        newWidth = (newHeight * width) / height;
                    } else { //portrait-mode
                        newWidth = 200;
                        newHeight = (newWidth * height) / width;
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        Bitmap sizeChanged = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, true);
        //Convert bitmap to a byte array
        int bytes = sizeChanged.getByteCount(); 
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
        sizeChanged.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bb); 
        picture = bb.array();
        //Write to a hd
        picturePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String fileName = edFile.getText().toString() + "_downscaled" + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(picturePath, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(picture);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
}
```

I tried several hours to get my `byte[] array` visible, but I could simply not do this. Any help or hints to show me where I derail is/are very appreciated.

Comment: The byte array you get from `copyPixelsFromBuffer()` contains the *raw* image pixel data as it appears in main memory. This data is certainly **not** JPEG-encoded, but a value array that needs to be interpreted according to the bitmap's pixel format. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: 1. downscaling my Bitmap relative to width/height. 2.  getting en new bitmap `sizeChanged`. 3.converting the new Bitmap instans to a `byte[] array´ --> `byte[] picture`. 4. writing `picture`to the file system to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was working for me

```
public static Bitmap byteArraytoBitmap(byte[] bytes) {
    return (BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));
}

public static byte[] bitmaptoByteArray(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //PNG format is lossless and will ignore the quality setting!
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

public static Bitmap bitmapFromFile(File file) {
    //returns null if could not decode
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
}

public static boolean saveImage(Bitmap image, String filePath) {
    LogInfo(TAG, "Saving image to: " + filePath);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    File fileDirectory = new File(file.getParent());
    LogInfo(TAG, fileDirectory.getPath());

    if (!fileDirectory.exists()) {
        if (!fileDirectory.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR CREATING DIRECTORIES");
            return false;
        }
    }

    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(bitmaptoByteArray(image));
        fo.flush();
        fo.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried your method: `bitmaptoByteArray` and it went well, i mean the converting(`bitmap` to `byte []`). But i don't understand why the size after downscaling (88Kb) > size before(83KB)? The objective med downscaling including dimensions was to reduce the size too! - Reults are from a test i just maded.

Comment: If you want to reduce the size, change the format to jpeg and drop quality down a bit. Say 70-80% of original. Tough I agree a smaller image should take less space indeed. Something is wrong.

Comment: Now everything goes smoothly. Thank you for using your time to help me, i have spent lot of time on this.